# What is the linux command to move the files of subdirecties into one level up respectively

Tags: linux, find, mv

The path structure of the files on my server is similar to that shown below,

/home/sun/sdir1/mp4/file.mp4
/home/sun/collection/sdir2/mp4/file.mp4

I would like to move the files of "mp4"  into one level up(into sdir1 and sdir2 respectively)

So the output should be,

/home/sun/sdir1/file.mp4
/home/sun/collection/sdir2/file.mp4

> I have no idea to do this, so not tried yet anything...

Comment: `mv` is the command to move files

Comment: do you want to do this in bulk using a shell script or do you just want to do the command each time?

Comment: But i want to move the files of more than one directories into their respective destination as i have discussed in the question.

Comment: @iShaymus,  yes i want to do this in bulk....

Comment: What is consistent with the file paths?  are they all on the same drive?  do they all have the /mp4/ folder?

Comment: @iShaymus,  yes they all are on the same drive and they all have /mp4/ folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to solve your problem

1. If you just want to move those specific files, run these commands:

   ```sh
   cd /home/sun/
   mv sdir1/mp4/file.mp4 sdir1/
   mv sdir2/mp4/file.mp4 sdir2/
   ```
2. If you want to move all mp4 files on those directories (sdir1 and sdir2), run these commands:

   ```sh
   cd /home/sun/
   mv sdir1/mp4/*.mp4 sdir1/
   mv sdir2/mp4/*.mp4 sdir2/
   ```

**Edit:**

3. Make a script that iterates all the directories:

Create a script and name it and edit it with your favorite editor (nano, vim, gedit, ...):

```
gedit folderIterator.sh
```

The script file content is:

```sh
#/bin/bash

# Go to the desired directory
cd /home/sun/

# Do an action over all the subdirectories in the folder
for dir in /home/sun/*/
do
    dir=${dir%*/}
    mv "$dir"/mp4/*.mp4 "$dir"/

    # If you want to remove the subdirectory after moving the files, uncomment the following line
    # rm -rf "$dir"
done
```

Save the file and give it execute permissions:

```
chmod +x folderIterator.sh
```

And execute it:

```
./folderIterator.sh
```

Comment: I have not only these 2 directories, it is more than 5k...but i do not want to execute the command 5k time...

Comment: I added a script that iterates over the subdirectories on /home/sun/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
# move all .mp4 files from sdir1/mp4 to sdir1 directory
user@host:~/home/sun$ mv sdir1/mp4/*.mp4 sdir/

# move all .mp4 files from collection/sdir2/mp4 to collection/sdir2 directory
user@host:~/home/sun$ mv collection/sdir2/mp4/*.mp4 collection/sdir2/

# move only 1 file
user@host:~/home/sun$ mv sdir1/mp4/file.mp4 sdir/
user@host:~/home/sun$ mv collection/sdir2/mp4/file.mp4 collection/sdir2/
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `find` and something like

```
cd /home/sun/sdir1/mp4/
find . -name "*" -exec mv {} /home/sun/sdir1/ \;
cd /home/sun/collection/sdir2/mp4/
find . -name "*" -exec mv {} /home/sun/collection/sdir2/ \;
```

Alternatively, you could use `tar` and something like

```
cd /home/sun/sdir1/mp4/
tar cfp - * | (cd ../ ; tar xvvf -)
# Make sure everything looks good
rm -rf mp4
cd /home/sun/collection/sdir2/mp4/
tar cfp - * | (cd ../ ; tar xvvf -)
# Make sure everything looks good
rm -rf mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to move a file (or directory) up one level is:

```
mv /home/sun/sdir1/mp4/file.mp4 ..
```

Wildcards can be used to select more files & directories, you can also provide more than one directory at a time.

```
mv /home/sun/sdir1/mp4/*.mp4 /home/sun/collection/sdir2/mp4/*.mp4 ..
```